# Query to return all Oracle Deadlocks in 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, deadlock

Is there an object I can query in 12c to return all ORA-60 Deadlock alerts?

I just want to do a weekly report that outputs the number of deadlocks that have occurred and what schema they occurred on.

My Oracle knowledge is not great, and I have drawn a blank when searching for resources on this online.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
select
  ss.value
from  
  v$sysstat ss 
  join v$statname sn using (statistic#)
where
  sn.name = 'enqueue deadlocks'
;
```

I did not test it extensively though.

Comment: This seems to give me a number, but I'm not sure what time period it is for, and I'd like to break it down by schema if possible

Comment: @Molenpad It is the number of deadlocks since instance startup. I am not aware of any semi-reliable method that gives this information by schemas other than analyzing all the trace files created on deadlock occurences.

Answer (score 1):

The deadlocks are reported to the alert log with the error ora-00060 if I remember well, and with X$DBGALERTEXT you should be able to "query" the alert log, based on that you should be able to create a query where you can get the deadlocks occurred during some window (days, weeks, etc) as long as you have the info in the alert log.